# How can I evaluate the result of a boolean expression in string format on runtime in C#?

Tags: c#, linq, dynamic, expression

Lets say I read this condition from a file:

```
Condition = "Person.Value.Status == 9"
```

How can I check if this condition is true in runtime providing that "Person" is a class in my code?

Comment: you mean Person is a variable in your code (not a class)?

Comment: Are the conditions, that you are reading from file, in certain format? Say for e.g. <ClassName>.<Property> <Operator> <Value> ?

Comment: Otherwise you could compile any code using CodeDom.

Comment: The problem is fixed by adding the reference both to the project and the code that I am creating on runtime.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While I haven't personally done this myself, [this](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/recipes/eval3.aspx) might be what you're looking for. It's an expression evaluater which is what I think you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Thank you. I tried to compile the code but it has an error for an unrecognized type and says "Did you miss adding a using directive or reference?". The problem is the type that I am using is defined in another project in the solution. So, something like this 'compilerParameters.ReferencedAssemblies.Add("OtherProject.dll");' does work. Any Idea?

Comment: Sorry I can't really help on this. Like I said, I've never done this type of thing before, just that it's possible and that others have built out frameworks for it.

Answer (score 2):

It may be an overkill to use Spring Framework for this, but it does have nice expression evaluator.

```
ExpressionEvaluator.GetValue(null, "2 == 2")  // true

ExpressionEvaluator.GetValue(null, "date('1974-08-24') != DateTime.Today")  // true

ExpressionEvaluator.GetValue(null, "2 < -5.0") // false

ExpressionEvaluator.GetValue(null, "DateTime.Today <= date('1974-08-24')") // false

ExpressionEvaluator.GetValue(null, "'Test' >= 'test'") // true
```

Check [documentation page](http://www.springframework.net/doc-latest/reference/html/expressions.html).

Answer (score 2):

You can add a reference to `Microsoft Script Control` and start to use JavaScript to check your condition. Here is a simple example

```
[System.Runtime.InteropServices.ComVisible(true)]
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    [System.Runtime.InteropServices.ComVisible(true)]    
    public class Person
    {
        public int Status = 9;
    }

    public Person person = new Person();

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MSScriptControl.ScriptControlClass script = new MSScriptControl.ScriptControlClass();
        script.Language = "JavaScript";

        script.AddObject("myform", this,true); 

        var b =  script.Eval("myform.person.Status==9");
    }
}
```

To avoid  to repeatedly add `[System.Runtime.InteropServices.ComVisible(true)]` You can change the line in AssemblyInfo.cs from `[assembly: ComVisible(false)]` to `[assembly: ComVisible(true)]`