# Equivalent VBs -> C# : Eval and Execute

Tags: c#, vbscript

I try to convert a part of code from VBScript to C#. 
I have these lines :

```
string replacementMatch = ....;
```

...

```
replacementMatch = Eval(replacementMatch);
```

OR

```
Execute(replacementMatch);
```

I can't find the equivalent in C#.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Eval function evaluates an expression and returns the result. You will not find an equivalent in statically typed languages such as C# and VB.NET. There are some libraries that provide such functionality such as [flee](http://flee.codeplex.com/).

Answer (score 0):

You can't find exactly the same functionality but you can use `CodeDomProvider` to compile an assembly from generated code and use `Reflection` to invoke methods from it.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a reference to `Microsoft Script Control` and call its Eval function in c#.
See this answer.

[How can I evaluate the result of a boolean expression in string format on runtime in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8068164/how-can-i-evaluate-the-result-of-a-boolean-expression-in-string-format-on-runtim/8068688#8068688)

Answer (score 0):

You will not find an equivalent. You could use the C# compiler, but it's never a good idea to execute arbitrary code in you applications. Consider your requirements, and see if writing a simple parser would be feasible. Check out System.Linq.Expressions in that case.

Answer (score 0):

In the documentation VBScript you can find that "Eval" and "Execute" arguments are evaluated as "as a VBScript expression". So in short words there are no C# equivalents.

In general you should review the vb code and consider rewrite it in C# to not require evaluating script at the runtime.

If you really need to create statements at runtime and evaluate them, you could try third party tools - like "http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dotnet/evaluator.aspx" (although I didn't used this particular tool - I could see very few situations when this is really needed).